# why tradingview pine editor showing this error "Undeclared identifier 'period'"

Tags: editor, indicator, tradingview-api

I am trying to create an indicator where I want the current price of the script and for that, I want to use tickerid and security()
this is my code

````
// © Tiger2dec

//@version=4
strategy("suresh banknifty", overlay=true)
src = input(close, title="Source")
// current volume 
cvolume= volume

//vwap
close1=close
vwap1=vwap(close1)
plot(vwap1)

//rsi
rsi=rsi(close,14)

//current price
price = security(syminfo.tickerid, period, src)

longCondition = cvolume>50000 and rsi>50
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)```


but its showing error  `Save operation failed, reason: line 19: Undeclared identifier 'period'`
````

Answer (score 0):

Use Period like this

> price = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, src)
> plot(price)

```
price = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, src)
```

plot(price)